# How to program application to re-speak differently?

Tags: iphone, ios

How to program application to re-speak differently  ( audio )

Possible with the help and guidance of experts ? 
 What are the basics to build this application ?

Comment: What do you mean by "re-speak differently"?

Comment: Means such as the work of the application ( tom cat talking )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this tutorial in maniacdev](http://maniacdev.com/2011/08/tutorials-how-to-change-pitch-instantenously-without-changing-tempo-like-the-talking-tom-app/). It has sample project too. Probably that is what you are trying to achieve.